# Number of views allowed to store in database

Tags: view, limit, firebird

Is there a limit to the number of views that I can create and store in a database or specifically Firebird? So far, I only managed to find the maximum number of tables that can be stored in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird considers views a form of tables, and as such the limit on the number of tables includes views (and system tables, and virtual tables like the monitoring tables).

This limit is 32768 (see https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-technical-specifications/).

Comment: hi, thank you for ur reply, can i ask do you know where I can find the documentation / article that state that "views are considered as a form of tables in firebird"?

Comment: @Lyn There is no such explicit statement that I'm aware of. It derives from the fact that views and tables are stored in the `RDB$RELATIONS` table, which use a `SMALLINT` for the relation-id. As far as the implementation of Firebird is concerned, views are simply a type of table.